# just started to learn coding, simple question

Tags: c, printf

please forgive my beginner code.
I don't understand why the last print function doesn't display correct x and y values, because I didn't manipulate them in any way. help? The last xy print I wanted was just the initial value I wrote at 8,9 column.

also as a total beginner, any advice will be great. thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int y2;
    int x2;
    // def x val
    // def y val
    int x = 50;
    int y = 12;

    for (int y2 = 1; y2 <= y; y2++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int x2 = 1; x2 <= x; x2++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
    }
    
    if (x = x2, y = y2)
    {
        printf("\nit is done, %i width, ", x2);
        printf("%i height.", y2);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, remember the difference between *assignment* using `=` and *comparison for equality* using `==`. Then if you want to do two comparisons you can't do it using the comma operator, you need to chain your conditions using logical and `&&` or logical or `||`.

Comment: On a different note, you can use multiple format code and arguments in a single `printf` call: `printf(it is done, %i width, %i height.\n", x2, y2);`

Comment: @user3121023 how do I get the variables inside the loop?

Comment: the last xy print I wanted was just the initial value I wrote at 8,9 column

Comment: **advice for beginners**: turn on the maximum warnings/warning level from your compiler and **mind the warnings!**

Comment: The first part of a `for` loop statement doesn't have to be a declaration, it can any kind of expression. Like for example an assignment: `for(y2 = 0; y2 <= y; y2++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charlie, my contribution in order for you to achieve the output you were expecting.

1. X2 and Y2 variables are already declared in the main block, you don't have to declare them in your for loops.

```c
    for (y2 = 1; y2 <= y; y2++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (x2 = 1; x2 <= x; x2++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
    }
```

2. At the bottom, you are not performing a comparison, you are performing an assignment, I assume that you were trying to check if "x is equal to AND y is equal to Y2).

```c
    if (x == x2 && y == y2)
```

3. In the same if statement, notice that the loops exit because Y2 is not smaller than or EQUAL to Y and because X2 is not smaller than or EQUAL to X. I assume that this was not your intent, due to to the last if block, so your conditions on the loop should probably be like this, "less than" and "starting at zero", so that you perform them exactly X and Y times.

```c
for (y2 = 0; y2 < y; y2++)
for (x2 = 0; x2 < x; x2++)
```

4. The code may be simplified even further, if you display the expected width and height directly from X and Y variables, see a complete example below, as posted in the comments by @TedLyngmo. In such case, maybe the for loop comparisons could be done as you initially made, unless you actually want X2 and Y2 not to be greater than X and Y for using them again later on (and even then, you could use X and Y directly for such purposes).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 50;
    int y = 12;

    for (int y2 = 0; y2 < y; y2++) 
    {        
        for (int x2 = 0; x2 < x; x2++) 
            putchar('#');

        putchar('\n');
    }

    printf("it is done, %i width, %i height.\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you mention "I didn't manipulate them in any way", you have accidentally done just that here:

`if (x = x2, y = y2)`

When you use a single `=`, that is the assignment operator, so you have assigned `x` the value of `x2` and `y` the value of `y2`. If the value of `y2` is non-zero, the `if` body will execute with those new values.

But with that condition as written, only the value of `y2` is being used to decide if the `if` body executes or not due to how the comma operator works. You probably wanted something like this

`if(x == x2 && y == y2)`

to only execute the `if` body if both match, or

`if(x == x2 || y == y2)`

to check if one of them are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Lets check your code line by line.

1. In below 2 lines, since variables are not assigned with any value, So these are having currently garbage value it could be 0 or any positive or -ve number.
   int y2;
   int x2;
2. For both the for() statements y2 and x2 are being assigned a value equals to 1 and is being changed in the loop itself but note the scope will be limited to those for() statements only. outside the scope of for() they will still have garbage value.
3. if (x = x2, y = y2)
   Above if() statement you are assigning x2 to x and y2 to y. So technically x and y also have garbage value also since ',' is used only y=y2 will be evaluated as per C.
   If garbage value is positive inside of if will be printed with same garbage values else if value garbage value of y2 is zero nothing will be printed.

I have added some print statements before and after kindly execute the code again with those print statements to understand with example what I am trying to say in point 1,2 and 3.

Also if you wished to compare x with x2 and y with y2 then you must have used == operator with || or && to prepare if condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int y2;
    int x2;
    //int y2 = 100;
    //int x2 = 100;
    // def x val
    // def y val
    int x = 50;
    int y = 12;

    printf("\nb4 if, %i width, ", x2);
    printf("%i b4 if height.", y2);

    for (int y2 = 1; y2 <= y; y2++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int x2 = 1; x2 <= x; x2++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
    }

    if (x = x2, y = y2)
    {
        printf("\nit is done, %i width, ", x2);
        printf("%i height.", y2);
    }
    printf("\nit is done, %i width, ", x2);
    printf("%i height.", y2);
}
```